# MongoDB (Mongoose) make array part of schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema, nosql

I'm creating a chat application with MongoDB (mongoose) and Nodejs. As you see below I have a schema as mongoose allows but my **users** in **storeSchema** needs to be an array of Strings (usernames). Is this the proper way to do it?

```
"use strict";
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: String
});

var messageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    msg: String
});

var storeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    users: [userSchema], // needs to be an array of users
    channels: {
        general: {
            messages: [messageSchema]
        },
        videogames: {
            messages: [messageSchema]
        },
        programming: {
            messages: [messageSchema]
        },
        other: {
            messages: [messageSchema]
        }
    }
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
var Message = mongoose.model('Message', messageSchema);
var Storage = mongoose.model('Storage', storeSchema);

module.exports = {
    User: User,
    Message: Message,
    Storage: Storage
}
```

Comment: If you want `users` to be an array of strings, then define it in the schema as `users: [String]`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was going for. I was unsure if I had to define it in the userSchema or the storeSchema..

Answer (score 0):

If you want `users` to be an array of username strings, then define it in `storeSchema` as:

```
users: [String]
```